# Building a histogram faster

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I am working with a large dataset that I need to build a histogram of. I feel like my method of just going through the entire list and marking in a second array the frequency is a slow approach. Any suggestions on how to speed the process up?

Comment: What you're describing sounds like O(N). Given that you need the count of all values, I don't see how you can improve on that (at least in terms of computational complexity).

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was thinking because you do need to read each item at least once. Thats unfortunate though, as my data is in the range of 100 million+

Comment: The obvious possibility for improvement would be parallel execution -- counting items for a histogram falls into the "embarrassingly parallel"  category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that a histogram is a graph containing the counts of all items in each bin, you can't make one without visiting all the items.

However, you can:

1. Create the histogram as you collect the data. Then it takes no time to generate.
2. Break up the data into N parts, and work on each part in parallel. When each part is done counting, just sum the results for each bin. (You can also combine this with #1)
3. Sample the data. In theory, looking at a fraction of your data, you should be able to estimate the rest of it.  [The Math](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section2/prc252.htm).

Comment: Solution 2 sounds like my best bet. Thanks.

Comment: Also, Amazon is your friend.  You can point-and-click to get Hadoop (EMR) or data warehouse (RedShift). https://aws.amazon.com/big-data/